# How to disable unnecessary autocomplete suggestions in VS Code?

Tags: typescript, autocomplete, visual-studio-code

I'm seeing strange autocompletion suggestions in VS Code that don't seem to have any context. I am expecting only the suggestions that come from my TS typings. These are properly shown on top of the suggestions list but then there's a bunch of options that are confusing to me, e.g. `#endregion`, `#region`, `async arrow function`, ...

[image]

Does anyone know:

- Where they come from?
- How to disable them?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Found the answer myself, it's this setting:

[image]

```json
{
    "editor.snippetSuggestions": "none"
}
```

Comment: With VSCode 1.63 we have [multiple language specific settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_63#_multiple-language-specific-editor-settings), which we can use to delimit the snippet hiding. For example, I'm using it for _TypeScript_ and _TypeScript React_ files, so this setting goes under `"[typescript][typescriptreact]"`.